# What is a faster way of compressing this data?

Tags: python, compression, huffman-code

I have a program that computes a ton of data and writes it to a file. My data is just a bunch of numbers from 0-16 (17 different values), and I have computed the frequency that each number appears in the data. I need to use as little disk space and as little RAM as possible, so I wrote a little Huffman encoding/decoding module in pure python that writes/read the compressed data with as few encoded symbols in memory at a time. Is there a module that comes with python that can do something similar? Here is the code with a little examples of how it will be used (**WARNING** the code is kinda long decently commented):

```
def makeTree(data):
    """data is a list of tuples, whos first entry is a priority/frequency
    number, and whos second entry is tuple containing the data to
    be encoded. The tree uses an internal tag system to tell where the
    branch ends. (End nodes are terminated with a False)"""
    def tag(data):
        taggedData = []
        for priority, datum in data:
            #all of the initial data is an end branch
            taggedData += [(priority, (datum, False))]
        return taggedData
    #get the tagged data into decending order of priority/frequency
    tree = sorted(tag(data), reverse=True)
    while len(tree)>1:
        #get the two lowest priority branches
        bottomR, bottomL = tree.pop(), tree.pop()
        #and stick them together into a new branch with combined priority
        new_elem = bottomR[0]+bottomL[0], ((bottomL, bottomR), True)
        #then add them back to the list of branches and sort
        tree += [new_elem]
        tree.sort(reverse=True)
    return tree[0]

def makeTable(tree, code=""):
    """Takes a tree such as generated by makeTree and returns a dictionary
    of code:value pairs."""
    #if this is an end branch, return code:value pair
    if tree[1][1]==False:
        return {code:tree[1][0]}
    #otherwise find the tables for the left and right branches
    #add them to the main table, and return
    table = {}
    table.update(makeTable(tree[1][0][0], code+'0')) #left
    table.update(makeTable(tree[1][0][1], code+'1')) #right
    return table

class Decoder:
    """this class creates a Decoder object which is used to decode a compressed
    file using the appropriate decoding table (duh). It used to be a function,
    but it was buggy and would also be ugly if I left it a function. (this
    class was written After the Encdoer class.)
    """
    def __init__(self, fname, table):
        self.file = open(fname)
        self.table = table
        self.byte = None
        self.bit = 7
        self.newByte = True

    def decode(self, size=1):
        """Decodes and yields size number of symbols from the file.
        Size defaults to 1"""
        #a counter for how many symbols were read
        read = 0
        code = ''
        while read<size:
            if self.newByte:
                self.byte = ord(self.file.read(1))
            for n in xrange(self.bit, -1, -1):
                code += str((self.byte & 1<<n) >> n)
                self.byte &= (1<<n)-1
                if code in self.table:
                    yield self.table[code]
                    read += 1
                    code = ''
                    if read==size:
                        self.bit = n-1
                        self.newByte = False
                        raise StopIteration
            self.bit = 7
            self.newByte = True

    def close(self):
        self.file.close()

class Encoder:
    """This class creates an encoder object, which is used to write encoded data
    to a file. It was initially going to be a function, but I couldn't
    accomplish that without code getting really ugly. :p """
    def __init__(self, fname, table):
        self.file = open(fname, 'w')
        self.table = table
        self.code = ''

    def encode(self, datum):
        """Attempts to write encoded datum to file. If their isn't enough
        code to write a whole number amount of bytes, then the code is saved up
        until there is."""
        self.code += self.table[datum]
        if len(self.code)%8==0:
            self.__write_code_chunk()
        return

    def end_encode(self):
        """Writes any remaining code to the file, appending the code with
        trailing zeros to fit within a byte, then closes the file."""
        #if the length of the code remaining isn't a multiple of 8 bits
        if len(self.code)%8:
            #then add zeros to the end so that it is
            self.code += "0"*(8 - len(self.code)%8)
        self.__write_code_chunk()
        self.file.close()
        return

    def __write_code_chunk(self):
        bytes = len(self.code)/8
        #for every byte (or every 8 bits)...
        for _ in xrange(bytes):
            #turn those bits into an number using int with base 2,
            #then turn the number into an ascii character,
            #and finally write the data to the file.
            self.file.write(chr(int(self.code[:8], 2)))
            #then get rid of the 8 bits just read
            self.code = self.code[8:]
        #make sure there is no code left over
        assert self.code==''
        return

if __name__=="__main__":
    import random

    mandelbrotData = [
        (0.10776733333333334, 0),
        (0.24859, 1),
        (0.12407666666666667, 2),
        (0.07718866666666667, 3),
        (0.04594733333333333, 4),
        (0.03356, 5),
        (0.023286666666666664, 6),
        (0.018338, 7),
        (0.014030666666666667, 8),
        (0.011918, 9),
        (0.009500666666666668, 10),
        (0.008396666666666667, 11),
        (0.006936, 12),
        (0.006365999999999999, 13),
        (0.005466, 14),
        (0.0048920000000000005, 15),
        (0.2537393333333333, 16)]
    decode_table = makeTable(makeTree(mandelbrotData))
    encode_table = {val:key for key, val in decode_table.iteritems()}
    approx_data = sum([[val]*int(round(freq*10**3/2)) for freq, val in mandelbrotData], [])
    random.shuffle(approx_data)

    testname = 'hufftest'
    encoder = Encoder(testname, encode_table)

    for val in approx_data:
        encoder.encode(val)
    encoder.end_encode()

    decoder = Decoder(testname, decode_table)
    decoded = list(decoder.decode(len(approx_data)/2))
    decoded += list(decoder.decode(len(approx_data)/2))
    print approx_data == decoded
```

Is there a module that can do something similar faster? If not, are there ways I can change my code to make it faster?

Comment: With real data, having to compute the frequency of occurrence of each value to do Huffman encoding is going to be relatively very time consuming. If you could pre-compute this and then just use a statistical model of the data it would speed that part of the process up considerable. Alternatively you might be able to do something very simple depending on the nature of your data. If many values are repeated consecutively, you might be able to just run-length encode them, which would be very fast, and might save a lot of memory. In other words, you may have to trade-off one goal against another.

Comment: Oh my gosh. you may have just inspired me! There are a TON of repeated consecutive values in my data (I think the first 300,000 values are all 17 :p !)

Comment: All 17? I thought you said the values ranged from 0-16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In memory the different occurrences of the same value do only use up one location.  The reference to them is repeated though.
- For disk storage, I'd probably just compress it with [zlib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html).

Comment: Correct.  zlib does Huffman coding, as well as referencing repeated strings for further compression.  Just put each 0..16 value in a byte, and compress the sequence of bytes with zlib.  (Note however that zlib is not zip.)

Comment: @MarkAdler zlib is compatible with gzip that's zip enough for me. Seriously though, I did mean compress when I said zip. Answer edited.

Comment: @cmd I ended up using pypng to make all the temporary files into pngs, which essentially does what you suggested. I was already using pypng to make the mandelbrot picture.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is significantly repetitious, then you might want to try just run-length encoding it which might be a relatively fast operation. Here's an implementation of one as a generator which could help minimize its overall memory usage. Note that when a run is very short, it only outputs the value rather than a (repeat-count,value) tuple to avoid bloating the output and possibly making it longer than it was originally.

```
from itertools import groupby

def run_length_encode(data):
    for value, igroup in groupby(data):
        repeat_count = len(list(igroup))
        yield value if repeat_count == 1 else repeat_count, value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    """ generate some random data with repeats and encode it """
    import random

    DATA_SIZE = 20
    MAX_VAL = 16
    MAX_REPEAT = 5
    data = []
    while len(data) < DATA_SIZE:
        val = random.randint(0, MAX_VAL)
        repeat = min(DATA_SIZE-len(data), random.randint(0, MAX_REPEAT))
        for _ in xrange(repeat): data.append(val)

    print data
    print [item for item in run_length_encode(data)]
```

Output:

```
[5, 5, 5, 9, 8, 8, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 7, 9, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16]
[(3, 5), 9, (2, 8), 7, (5, 5), 1, 7, 9, (5, 16)]
```

If the runs are very long, it might be better to explicitly count out how many are in each group iteratively instead of turning them into a lists and taking its length:

```
def ilen(iterable):
    """ return the number of items in an iterable """
    return sum(1 for _ in iterable)

def run_length_encode(data):
    for value, igroup in groupby(data):
#        repeat_count = len(list(igroup))
        repeat_count = ilen(igroup)
        yield value if repeat_count == 1 else repeat_count, value
```

Since the range of your data values is relatively small, you could (also) encode them into single-byte character values.